# How to Open Codes of a Project in VScode (windows) which is in Virtual Machine (Ubuntu) in AWS Instances

Tags: aws

I am working in AWS Instance > Ubuntu20.08.
There is a GoLang-JS project which I want to open and edit in the VScode of My computer (windows 10).
How to do it.

Comment: Please re-read your question & correct or clarify details.  Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, so 20.08 represents 2020-August where no release occurred, so what are you asking about.  (*Ubuntu also has specialist products that use the year format, eg. Ubuntu Core 20 is the 2020 release - but the are different systems*)

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways you can do this.

1. you can use Github to store a cloud central version of the code, which you push to update on your desktop, and pull to download on the aws server. This is the method I use for my code. You can setup webhooks on Github to automatically trigger a code update on the aws server if you want to take it a step further.
2. you can use WinSCP to set an automatic update on file detection between your windows machine and the aws machine. It's kind of top heavy, and performs lots of transfers, so that might not be the best.
3. you can use filezilla and setup a connection using sftp with the aws server, and manually transfer the new code each time.

Comment: 1st method sounds best. This one, right? :- 


docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/creating-webhooks

Comment: `git push -u origin main` on ubuntu VM give this error : 

Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.

Comment: @aakash4dev - Yep, that's the right. You'll need a deploy server running but that's trivial. There are simple python web servers all the way to php and apache.

That error means the git configuration for Ubuntu VM is trying to use a password to push the code to Github. You'll need to create a key pair first. On the VM, open a terminal and run ```ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "Github"```. Then run ```cat .ssh/id_ed25519.pub```. Copy that output. Open your Github account and create a new key pair. [link](https://github.com/settings/keys)

Answer (score 1):

there's an extension you can try to work with if you have SSH access.

It's called [Remote - SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) and it's owned by Microsoft.

1. Open the command palette with `CTRL+Shift+P`
2. Select "*Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...*"
3. Follow the config steps.